# XBox One Green Screen of Death

Tags: xbox-one

Just got my XBOX One today (the first day it's available) and can't get past the green boot screen.  Has anyone else had this problem and figured out how to get past it?   Hold times for Microsoft Support are ridiculous right now, so I can't get through.

Comment: How long have you waited at the boot screen?  Have you tried power cycling the console?

Comment: Remember that it takes some time to boot up, load the Day One patch, et cetera... Took me all in all 30 minutes for my first boot up.

Comment: For myself, it took about the same as @Exa ~20 ish minutes to setup, ~5 of which was that green startup screen.  How long did you wait at that boot up screen?

Comment: Next time just buy a PS4. Problem solved.

Comment: Then i'd just be stuck with the problem of having the 2nd best console. XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the initial download and install of the updates for XBox live.   I finally was able to get through to MS support and the person was very helpful.  Here's a links they directed me to and they helped walk me through the process.

http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/system/offline-system-update-diagnostic-tool

Here's something on the xbox forum about the issue as well:

http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/xbox_one_support/f/4269/t/1630236.aspx

After walking through the steps, everything is working great now.  Initial role-outs are often glitchy.  Just the price you pay for being an early adopter.